# Remove dual boot safely for bootloader (GRUB2)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, xubuntu

I installed yesterday another linux (Antergos) beside my Xubuntu, and it didn't offer me what I wanted. Now I want to remove it, but I suspect it might generate a bootloader issue, as the bootloader became Antergos-themed and more specifically because I don't know if there's importance of the locations of partitions - The Antergos partition is the first memory-allocation-wise.

Is it safe to just delete it with `GParted` and combine it back to Xubuntu? Or are there additional stuff to do? beforehand/afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use `/dev/sda` as an example, make sure it's your actual hard drive.

Boot into Xubuntu, open a terminal and run:

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

This will reinstall GRUB2 in your disk's boot sector and put its essential files in the Xubuntu partition.

Then you can safely wipe Antergos' partition and run `sudo update-grub` afterwards so its GRUB entry will be removed.

Comment: They're both sda: sda3 (Antergos) comes first, then sda1 (Xubuntu). Does it mean I should `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1`?

Comment: NO!!! Do **not** install GRUB to a partition. It **must** be the entire disk, in your case also `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean to do a rash sudo that might erase the entire disk/partition. so the same steps basically? first reinstall on `/dev/sda`, then delete sda3?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You're completely right: never run anything as a superuser without making sure! We're always here to help you.